# simpleOpenNI multiple users

Tags: processing, kinect, simple-openni

I'm using simpleOpenNI with the Kinect. I have an array of 5 colors and a certain number of people (12-13) that will come in front of the kinect one by one. I need to relate a single color to a single person. When the index of the array of colors will arrive at 5, it will be reset to 0. My problem is that I cant' do something like 'new user = index++' because the userId doesn't seem to change everytime a person exit the kinect space and a new one enters in.
My problem is that I don't understand when/where a new user is detected.

I think I should do something in this part of code but not sure where

```
void draw()
{
  // update the cam
  context.update();

  // draw depthImageMap
  image(context.rgbImage(),0,0,200, 200);

  // draw the skeleton if it's available
  int[] userList = context.getUsers();
  for(int i=0;i<userList.length;i++)
  {
    if(context.isTrackingSkeleton(userList[i]))
    {
      stroke(userClr[ (userList[i] - 1) % userClr.length ] );
      drawSkeleton(userList[i]);
      draw_line(xL, yL, oldXL, oldYL, xR, yR, oldXR, oldYR);
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The automatic scene segmentation in OpenNI is nice, but not perfect.
Sometimes you'll notice parts of the background may merge with a user (if the background is complex) and the user detection is an estimation: it may not keep track of users entering/exiting the scene correctly.

Even with a user or two, you'll notice the same person exiting and entering the scene may be assigned a different user id and the best thing is to manage users yourself.

This may not be trivial, but perhaps you can try [OpenTSPS](http://www.tsps.cc/documentation/) since it provides some of this functionality and it [plays well with Processing](http://www.tsps.cc/tutorials/2012/11/4/tsps-processing)

[image: OpenTSPS Person Events]

[image: OpenTSPS Basics]

[image: OpenTSPS Advanced]